# Keytool: Can I use a Cert request config file to define CSR extension in Keytool? (similar to openssl - config)

Tags: openssl, keytool

I use an nCipher HSM to store my secret keys and I would like to generate a custom CSR, with custom extensions (alternate name, certificate policy and name constraints).

I am running the HSM in FIPS mode, which means the private keys cannot leave the HSM and have to be created by the HSM directly. Therefore I am not able to use openssl to generate the CSR. (This might be possible using an openSSL engine, but that seems like a huge amount of work).

Using KeyTool with a custom security provider I am able to connect to the HSM to manage keys in the HSM. For example:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore new_key_store_name.jks -storepass <mypassword> -storetype ncipher.sworld -providername nCipherKM
```

Now I would like to use something similar to create some custom CSR. I am using this command and it works for, let's say, a "basic" CSR.

```
keytool -certreq -alias <myalias> -file csr.txt -sigalg SHA256withECDSA -keystore new_key_store_name.jks -storepass <mypassword> -storetype ncipher.sworld -providername nCipherKM
```

What I am not able to do though is to add extension requests to it. In openssl, I am able to add the extension requests using a config file, but as I said above, I dont think openssl can use this custom security provider. Here is the openssl conf extract I am using for my tests.

```
[...]
    ####################################################################
    [ server_req_extensions ]

    subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
    basicConstraints     = CA:FALSE
    extendedKeyUsage     = serverAuth,clientAuth
    keyUsage             = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
    subjectAltName       = @alternate_names
    nsComment            = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"
    certificatePolicies  =  2.23.146.1.2.1.2
    nameConstraints      = permitted;IP:192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0
    nameConstraints      = permitted;email:max.somedomain.com

    ####################################################################
    [ alternate_names ]

    otherName=1.1.2.1;UTF8:"random-name"
```

So here is my question: is there a way to tell keytool to add those extension? Maybe using a similar config file? (plan A)
Or is there a way to have openSSL to using the HSM security provider? (plan B)

I have had some success using Java code to manipulate the ASN1 in my CSR with my HSM, but that's a very very tedious exercise. (plan C)

thanks in advance folks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can do it by using  `-ext`. So add these to your command line:

```
-ext KeyUsage:critical="digitalSignature, keyEncipherment" \
-ext BasicConstraints:critical="ca:False" \

etc..
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up doing it all manually in java. I ll get back to you if I end up looking into it again.